# SyntaxError: JSON.parse

Tags: php, json, webservice, web

tengo un WS simple, hecho en php, todo marchaba bien, lo consumo desde una aplicación Android, pero desde hace dias me muestra un error al hacer login, cosa de que no esta consumiendo correctamen el JSON debido a este problema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me sale al inicio del json un espacio en blanco.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    {"Login":[{"RFC":"LOOF8910077G2","0":"LOOF8910077G2","CLAVE_TRABAJADOR":"189010016","1":"189010016","EMAIL":null,"2":null,"Nombre":"JOSE FRANCISCOLOPEZORTIZ","3":"JOSE FRANCISCOLOPEZORTIZ"}]}
```

y este un pedazo de mi codigo PHP

**Consulta**

```
public function login($control,$pass){
        try{
            $sql ="SELECT RFC, CLAVE_TRABAJADOR, EMAIL,(NOMBRE + PATERNO + MATERNO) AS Nombre FROM trabajad WHERE RFC = '$control' AND PWD = '$pass'";
                //$query = $this->con->query($sql);
                /*$data=Array();
                $query = sqlsrv_query($this->con,$sql);
                $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query);
                //$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);*/
                $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute(); 
                $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                return $row;

            }catch(PDOException $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }//Fin login
```

y el codigo donde obtengo el retorno de la consulta

```
header("Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8");
$db = new Conexion;
$trabajador = new Trabajador($db);

$foto = $_POST['foto'];//Obtengo la imagen para guardarla en el servidor
//$foto = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']));
$clave = $_POST['clave'];
$token = $_POST['token'];

switch ($_REQUEST['op']) {
    case 'login':
        //$rfc = isset($_GET['rfc']) ? limpiarCadena($_GET['rfc']):"";
        //$contra = isset($_GET['contra']) ? limpiarCadena($_GET['contra']):"";
    $rfc = $_GET['rfc'];
    $contra = $_GET['contra'];

    $respuesta = $trabajador->login($rfc,$contra);
    $data=Array();
    foreach ($respuesta as $elemento ) {
            $data["Login"][]=$elemento;
                # code.../
        }
    echo json_encode($data);
    /*if (!empty($respuesta)) {
            # code...

        foreach ($respuesta as $elemento ) {
            $data["Login"][]=$elemento;
                # code.../
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    }else{
        echo json_encode("Mal");
    }*/
    break;
```

Comment: Muestra un `var_dump($data);`  por favor. Con una imagen truncada poco podemos hacer, ¿por qué no pones el texto del JSON completo?

Comment: Listo subi la imagen con un var_dump

Comment: En vez de imágenes ayuda más que pongas el texto en sí. Las imágenes no se pueden re-utilizar y no se ven bien en dispositivos pequeños. Gracias.  Y pon el JSON, no veo de dónde sale ese espacio en blanco del que hablas, ni tampoco veo donde está. También se ve que tu código PHP  te duplica información, eso no es bueno, sobrecarga las peticiones a la API.

Comment: Así está bien? ya puse el json y los codigos php

Comment: Yo no sé que es esa imagen que muestras y que consideras como espacio en blanco ¿?  tu JSON es válido, según [`jsonlint` (lo puedes copiar y pegar allí y validar)](https://jsonlint.com), ¿quizá tu problema esté leyendo el JSON en Android?  Voy a revisar tu PHP ahora que lo pusiste...

Comment: Ya lo probé en jsonlint y también marca el syntax error, el espacio en blanco esta antes de que empieza el JSON es como una tabulacion

Comment: Pues te dije que copies y pegues el JSON tal cual lo recibes. Yo copié el JSON que pusiste en la respuesta, con el espacio de la izquierda y todo, lo pegué en jsonlint y me dice que es válido.  No entiendo por qué a ti no te valida.

Comment: Si quieres haz esto: `$json=json_encode($data); var_dump($json);`  si se crease un json erróneo debería imprimirte `FALSE`, ya que `json_encode` devuelve `FALSE` cuando no se puede crear un json válido.

Comment: ya, me retorna esto  string(191) "{"Login":[{"RFC":"LOOF8910077G2","0":"LOOF8910077G2","CLAVE_TRABAJADOR":"189010016","1":"189010016","EMAIL":null,"2":null,"Nombre":"JOSE FRANCISCOLOPEZORTIZ","3":"JOSE FRANCISCOLOPEZORTIZ"}]}"

Comment: Te paso el link de donde se hace la peticion?

Comment: El JSON es correcto, de lo contrario te mostraría `false`. No me sirve de nada el link si hace falta un token. ¿El error dónde lo muestra, porque no termino de entender de dónde sacas la imagen del espacio en blanco?

Comment: El código que compartes tiene problemas de seguridad y es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Curiosamente usas sentencias preparadas... pero para una consulta creada dinámicamente concatenando cadenas de manera insegura. Lee sobre inyección SQL y cómo prevenirla en PHP.

Comment: Tal vez no es la generación del JSON lo que da problema, sino que tienes por ahí un espacio entre etiquetas php de cierre/apertura, como **?>   <?php** o, el archivo php está codificado en UTF8 con BOM y ese caracter es el que causa todo el problema; de ser el caso, solo tienes que cambiar a UTF8 sin BOM y listo.